# Retrieving bytearray from database in servlet and in jsp

Tags: java, image, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am really not understanding the byte arrays...may be because i am working on images for the first time so need your help

I have base64 string *R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==*

which i am decoding and storing it in MySql database then i am using following code on my servlet side

```
if ( request.getParameter("imgID") != null )
    {

      iNumPhoto = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("imgID")) ;   


      try
      {  
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
               conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:9191/mbcss","root","admin");
               stmt= conn.createStatement();

         //conn.setAutoCommit (false);  

         // get the image from the database
         byte[] imgData = GetPhoto.getPhoto( conn, iNumPhoto );   
         System.out.println("imgData="+imgData);
         // display the image
         response.setContentType("image/gif");
         OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
         o.write(imgData);

         o.flush(); 
         o.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();

      }
    }
         }
```

here is getPhoto method

```
public static byte[] getPhoto (Connection conn, int iNumPhoto)
throws Exception, SQLException
{
 String req = "" ;
 Blob img ;
 byte[] imgData = null ;
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement ();

 // Query
 req = "Select image From visit";

 ResultSet rset  = stmt.executeQuery ( req ); 

 while (rset.next ())
 {    
  img = rset.getBlob(1);
  imgData = img.getBytes(1,(int)img.length());
 }    

 rset.close();
stmt.close();

 return imgData ;
}
```

visit table has only 1 record but whenever i execute my jsp file which invokes servlet class **imgData** which i have printed on my console is printing different value on each refresh and image is also not displayed on JSP

1. Displaying different value every time is coding error or characterstics of byte array.
2. Why image is not displayed help me out

Comment: Decoding the image might be the reason why the image is not correctly getting displayed in the JSP. Try storing the image data straight into db without decoding.

Comment: @Ravindra Gullapalli you mean to say i should store the image as base64 string only...well that will be too inefficient for me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following:

1. In your query "Select image From visit" I don't see the WHERE clause for restrict the result, so if you have many rows it can be the reason for obtain different result every time that you refresh the page.
2. The field image is of type BLOB in database?

EDIT:

Checking the documentation of MySQL you need to follow some rules. First the method must be getBytes not getBlob. The other rules are:

> Starting with Connector/J version 3.1.0, you can emulate BLOBs with
>   locators by adding the property emulateLocators=true to your JDBC URL.
>   Using this method, the driver will delay loading the actual BLOB data
>   until you retrieve the other data and then use retrieval methods
>   (getInputStream(), getBytes(), and so forth) on the blob data stream.
>
> You must use a column alias with the value of the column to the actual
>   name of the BLOB, for example:
>
> SELECT id, 'data' as blob_data from blobtable You must also follow
>   these rules:
>
> The SELECT must reference only one table. The table must have a
>   primary key.
>
> The SELECT must alias the original blob column name, specified as a
>   string, to an alternate name.
>
> The SELECT must cover all columns that make up the primary key.
>
> The BLOB implementation does not allow in-place modification (they are
>   copies, as reported by the DatabaseMetaData.locatorsUpdateCopies()
>   method). Because of this, use the corresponding
>   PreparedStatement.setBlob() or ResultSet.updateBlob() (in the case of
>   updatable result sets) methods to save changes back to the database.

You can check more at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html

Comment: i have already mentioned there is only 1 row as I had also tested with where clause but then deleted all rows except 1 for testing..so there is only 1 row and data type is BLOB

Comment: i dont have primary key in visit table..can you tell me what i should do...from your above document what changes now i should make

Comment: You MUST create a PK, if you don't want to use them you can create a column "id" with autoincrement feature. If you have your data in production you can create a temporal table with the PK, then load the data from old table and finally make a rename of the table.

Answer (score 0):

you will see the last image file from your record from blob database because the byat array flush it out every new record and replace new image file to the fix location in jsp page  you need to write file to the local dir and the need to give the path to that location

Comment: firstly i have only 1 record in my database..second i tried fileoutputstream to save image first to drive..some 9 bytes file is getting created but not the image in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are decoding the Base64 encoded image properly and also that there is no problem with the code that adds the image to the database.

Go through the reverse process: 
(1) Retrieve byte array image representation from the database 
(2) Do Base64 encoding on the byte array 
(3) Create a String from the Base64 encoded byte array.

The string you get by doing this must have the same value as the original one:
R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==

If that is the case, then you know you are doing the decoding and database storage correctly; otherwise if the values are different, you need to fix either the decoding or the database storage code.